# How to share multiple Images with WhatsApp using in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

This is the code for sharing only one image with WhatsApp. How can I share multiple images?

```
@IBAction func whatsappShareWithImages(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    let urlWhats = "whatsapp://app"
    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                if let image = UIImage(named: "whatsappIcon") {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
                        let tempFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai")
                        do {
                            try imageData.write(to: tempFile, options: .atomic)
                            self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tempFile)
                            self.documentInteractionController.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
                            self.documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                 UIAlertView(title: "Error",  message : "Please install the WhatsApp application", delegate:nil, cancelButtonTitle:"Ok").show()
                // Cannot open whatsapp
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can share multiple images to any using `UIActivityViewController`, code give below:

```
@IBAction func share(_ sender: Any) {

    let image1 = UIImage(named: "a.jpg")
    let image2 = UIImage(named: "b.jpg")
    let image3 = UIImage(named: "c.jpg")

    let dataToShare = [image1, image2, image3]

    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: dataToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: @KairaSupport Make sure that you accept correct answers by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

As per their [official documentation](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013/), they don't seem to support multiple image sharing via URL Scheme.

You can however use the iOS Share extension using [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller) or [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller) with extension `.wai` so only WhatsApp is shown in the list.